# I cannot figure out this Access Violation error. Can someone help me out here?

Tags: c++, oop, visual-studio-2012, access-violation

I cannot find where this problem is coming from and it is driving me insane! My main and a pastebin link are below. I keep getting this error:

`First-chance exception at 0x0FFE108E (msvcr110d.dll) in MasterMindFSM.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x2CF0D131.
Unhandled exception at 0x0FFE108E (msvcr110d.dll) in MasterMindFSM.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x2CF0D131.`

Here is my main:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Answer.hpp"

using namespace Games::MasterMind;

int main() {
   Answer Line;

   std::cout << Line.getAnswer(0) << std::endl;
   std::cout << Line.getAnswer(1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << Line.getAnswer(2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << Line.getAnswer(3) << std::endl;

   system("pause");

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file that accompanies main:
(Sorry, but it lost it's formatting)

[Answer.hpp](http://pastebin.com/bVHELPas/)

Comment: You can at least debug to find out what function you have causes it.

Comment: @chris It doesn't tell me. It just gives me the error.

Comment: You'll go out of bounds if `ran = rand() % 6 + 1` happens to be 6.

Comment: it should be `ran = ((rand() % 5) + 1);` to stay within 1->5.

Comment: THANK YOU! I need it in 0->5 range though. How would I do that?

Comment: To remain 0->5 you need to use `ran = ((rand() % 5));`

Comment: @Aniket, Actually, `rand() % 6`.

Comment: yeah you're right @chris `rand()%6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: What is "Line"?

Q: Does it's constructor allocate an Answer(0), Answer(1), Answer(2), ...?

Failure to allocate an entity before you use it can easily cause a segmentation violation ;)

======================================

I just looked at your (cleverly hidden ;)) "Answer.hpp".

PROBLEM:

1) "getAnswer()" looks perfectly OK (I thought that's where you were having problems)

2) The actual problem is in "setAnswer()" - you're running off the end of your array!

Comment: Line can be a stack object.

Comment: Did you look in the pastebin link? That should explain it.

Comment: No problem! This community helps me so much, I gotta support others! ;D